# Azure SQL: Azure SQL Database traffic migration to newer Gateways

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure

I have been assigned a task to look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-gateway-migration. I got an email about it:
[image: Part of email received from Microsoft]

I have a pretty standard setup, with a Azure SQL server and one database, that my services connect to through a connectionstring in some resoruce groups in Azure. Pretty standard and straight forward. I don't think I am affected by this, but still, I got the email, and now I have find out. I have never heard of gateways and such.

Do I need to do anything if my services and databases is completely hosted in Azure? I cannot read that from the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received the same email. I have received similar emails in the past. The only thing I do is add the IPs of the new gateways on the firewall rules on the Azure SQL Database logical server as shown on the image below.

[image]

Add the IP addresses of the gateways that belong to the zones where you have created your Azure SQL Database logical servers.

You do not have to do anything else. Based on my experience everything keeps working as usual.